# Adding an id variable in a linear model causes small coefficient and strange range of fitted values

Tags: categorical-data, regression-coefficients, fitting, range

So I'm trying to construct a linear model on a data set and the data set has an `id` variable that is a school id. The data set measures (or i.e. the response is) test scores and contains some other variables.

The `id` variable can take the following values:

```
  [1] 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009 1010 1011 1012 1013 1014 1015 1016
 [17] 1017 1018 1019 1020 1021 1022 1023 1025 1026 1027 1028 1029 1030 1031 1033 1034
 [33] 1036 1037 1038 1039 1040 1041 1042 1043 1044 1045 1046 1047 1048 1049 1050 1051
 [49] 1052 1053 1054 1055 1056 1057 1058 1059 1060 1061 1332 1635 2001 2002 2003 2004
 [65] 2005 2006 3001 3002 3003 3004 3005 3006 3007 3008 3009 3010 3011 3012 3013 3014
 [81] 3015 3016 3017 3018 3019 3020 3021 3022 3023 3024 3025 3026 3027 4001 4002 4003
 [97] 4004 4005 4006 4007 4008 5001 5002 5003 5004 5005 5006 5007 5008 5009 5010 5011
[113] 5012 6001 6002 6003 6004 6005 6006 6007 7001 7002 7003 7004 7005 7006 7007 7008
[129] 7009 7010 7011 7012 7014 8001 8002 8003 8004 8005 8006 9001
```

Now I wanted to try out `id` as the only variable, because I thought it would be reasonable to expect there to variation between different schools, like the better schools and the worse schools. And taking means based on the school id does show that there are some differences. However, when I construct a linear model with only the `id` variable I get:

```
Call:
lm(formula = dta$X.U.FEFF..mpist. ~ dta$id)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       dta$id  
  5.449e+02    2.438e-04
```

First notice the very small coefficient for `id`.

Secondly, the range of fitted values becomes very odd:

```
> range(fitted(fit1))
[1] 545.1571 547.1079
```

The test scores have a range of:

```
> range(dta$X.U.FEFF..mpist.)
[1] 296.706 783.462
```

So the range of fitted values should certainly be larger.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I think I need to use `factor()` to the `id` variable when making the model. However an explanation regarding why must I do this would be helpful.

Comment: If you don't make it a factor, R treats it as a number and tries to fit a linear model $y = \alpha + \beta * id$ so the assumption it is forcing is that performance is _linear_ in the actual id number.

Comment: @mavavilj you can post an answer to your own question.